# The redirect_uri URL must be absolute (Facebook login using php in localhost)

Tags: php, facebook

this is my config.php
how to redirect it to facebook from localhost? since localhost don't have "http://" ?

when I want to login and press the button. it said "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute"

```
<?php
/*!
* HybridAuth
* http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net | http://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth
* (c) 2009-2012, HybridAuth authors | http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/licenses.html
*/

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  HybridAuth Config file: http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/userguide/Configuration.html
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$config =array(
        "base_url" => "hybridauth/index.php", 
        "providers" => array ( 

            "Google" => array ( 
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "XXXXXXXXXXXX", "secret" => "XXXXXXXX" ), 
            ),

            "Facebook" => array ( 
                "enabled" => true,
                "keys"    => array ( "id" => "XXXXXXXXXXXX", "secret" => "XXXXXXXXXXXX" ), 
            ),

        "Twitter" => array ( 
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys"    => array ( "key" => "XXXXXXXX", "secret" => "XXXXXXX" ) 
        ),
    ),
    // if you want to enable logging, set 'debug_mode' to true  then provide a writable file by the web server on "debug_file"
    "debug_mode" => false,
    "debug_file" => "debug.log",
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` is same as `http://localhost`.

This should help

```
"base_url" => "http://localhost/hybridauth/index.php"
```

Comment: it work !
but there is an error again 
"URL provided is not allowed by the Application configuration .: One or more of the specified URL is not allowed by the app's settings. This URL must match the URL of the Web site or the Canvas URL, or sphere must be uparanah (subdomain) from one realm of this app."

Comment: well, then, add localhost as website platform in your app settings. meaning, just do what the error messages suggests.